# (NEWB) Installed Ubuntu from LiveCD, now what?

Tags: 14.04

I downloaded and burned the Ubuntu image to a DVD+R then proceeded to install it to a 30GB partition split from a 250GB drive which was done in Windows. I installed it there, but now what do I do? There is no option to boot into the new install when I start the computer. The partition doesn't show up in either boot menu or the My Computer window.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe GRUB wasn't isntalled correctly, or to the right drive/partition. Trying the **Boot-Repair** program might fix it https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

And does your computer also have Windows 8 / 8.1? This question might be helpful too, though you've already installed Ubuntu there still should be some booting info too... [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: It's running Vista. 7 year old tower now being used for general tech stuff.